# Under which conditions does it make sense to use Doctrine 2 instead of PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm

My question is not aiming at ORMs in general but specifically Doctrine 2!

Every mildly complex PHP-application uses a database.

And as much as it makes sense to seperate M, V and C it makes sense to seperate the M into DB-access-level and high-level objects.

Now I just had a superficial look at Doctrine 2 and it certainly seems all nice and dandy but **so far** I cannot see any reason what I will gain from this tool compared to using PDO-features like FETCH_CLASS, FETCH_OBJECT and FETCH_INTO combined with a reasonably structured collection of classes.

Of course I would have to write more code myself; but the difference does seem far from the speed I gain when developing with a framework instead of building a PHP-app from the scratch.

So if you know Doctrine **2**, then maybe you can tell me under what conditions Doctrine 2 should be seriously considered, b/c:

**it will speed up development substantially** (due to specific features)

this is the only reason that makes sense in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, it does speed up development by a substantial amount. The other comparison is 'preference' - Doctrine 2 feels more truly 'object orientated'. It's also important to note that Doctrine 2 uses transactions to execute queries to speed up execution time and although this can be done using PDO as you mentioned previously it requires you to write more code.

I guess it's like having your own PHP libs and using frameworks. It just 'speeds up' the development process and therefore it's an obvious winner with people writing large applications.

Comment: I didn't day that D2 speeds up dev - that's what I questioned, actually. / Transactions don't speed up exec but make data transmission more stable. / My questions is also aiming at my impression that even a complex web app doesn't need much library for the db-layer as there is not much logic handled really. just mapping of tables onto objects and back.

Comment: Well that's the thing.. ORM takes care of the mapping of tables onto objects and back for you. It's much like writing your own library but why re-invent the wheel? Doctrine 2 is pretty light-weight. See http://www.slideshare.net/jwage/doctrine-2-not-the-same-old-php-orm

Comment: for a complex data structure like a "real" tree one definitely needs a library anyway. but the usual relationally organized information pieces are trivially mapped onto objects, as D2 also doesn't seem to go beyond field<=>property. and this can be very nicely done using pdo. I am not sure if you have worked yet with this PHP feature.

Comment: just had a look at the slideshare ... they don't give any reason to use D2, only why you would change from D1 to D2 (maybe caching is an obvious bonus). especially this "comparison" to mysql-ext is very very wrong and misguided, as they totally misuse transactions here. this is a very bad joke at best and rather inclining me to NOT use D2 :-/